# DirectShow Run graph

Tags: directshow

This is no longer necessary to keep in forum for lack of poor format nor statistical data keeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the graph says it's running it doesn't really mean any activity is taking place, it just means the graph object told the filters to run and set its "state" variable to "running". However if any filter is stuck for any reason and doesn't send or receive the data everything freezes but the graph state remains "running".  Some editors like [GraphEditPlus](http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus/) can show states of each particular filter in the graph, so if some of them report to be stopped or paused while some others are still "running" you will see this. In most cases however you'll just see all filters "running" and won't know which of them is stuck unless you insert sample grabbers between them and tell GraphEditPlus to show grabbed samples in real time, this is a good way to understand what's really going on.